# Deserialize a nested json string using Json.net and C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My string json

```
{"data":[{"id":"CAMVqgY1g1cdLU5anDL69Tt5pyRh51-qkyKMHWHgH2mAG+vn+xQ%40mail.gmail.com","content":"Coba ngirim email mohon diterima\r\n","judul":"coba 1","sender":"\"Aldo Erianda\""},{"id":"CAMVqgY1Trb5ZShRxzoX%3D0xaVQs5-Psh0J8V3JwQYVevcr8i5WA%40mail.gmail.com","content":"sampai nga ya\r\n","judul":"coba 2","sender":"\"Aldo Erianda\""}]}
```

I want to count record inside "data", and show the records in console or richtextbox.
several tutorial still make me difficult to figure out. how should I do in step by step?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181983/json-net-deserialize-string-to-nested-class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your specific case.  It's not generalizable to any json string.

```
var json = "{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"CAMVqgY1g1cdLU5anDL69Tt5pyRh51-qkyKMHWHgH2mAG+vn+xQ%40mail.gmail.com\",\"content\":\"Coba ngirim email mohon diterima\r\n\",\"judul\":\"coba 1\",\"sender\":\"Aldo Erianda\"},{\"id\":\"CAMVqgY1Trb5ZShRxzoX%3D0xaVQs5-Psh0J8V3JwQYVevcr8i5WA%40mail.gmail.com\",\"content\":\"sampai nga ya\r\n\",\"judul\":\"coba 2\",\"sender\":\"Aldo Erianda\"}]}";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, JArray>>(json);
JArray recordList = deserialized["data"];
foreach (JObject record in recordList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + record["id"]);
    Console.WriteLine("content: " + record["content"]);
    Console.WriteLine("judul: " + record["judul"]);
    Console.WriteLine("sender: " + record["sender"]);
}
Console.WriteLine("count: " + recordList.Count);
```

Note: I slightly modified your json by escaping all the quotations to make it a valid C# string.  Also, I think you have extra quotations around the value of your sender.

Comment: it works.. just like what i expected..
anyway, do i need to make additional class like this below:

class ResponseEntity
    {
        public ResponseEntity()
        {
            data = new List<data>();
        }
        public List<data> data;
    }

    class data
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
        public string judul { get; set; }
        public string sender { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Depending on what your trying to accomplish, these classes could be useful.  I think the ResponseEntity class may be overkill.  I'd just store the information in a List<Data>.

Comment: could you please explain this part.. 
**var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, JArray>>(json);**
if you don't mind.

Comment: The json object is serialized as a string.  We want to deserialize the string so we can parse and use the values in the json object.  The thing is, we need to deserialize (i.e. translate) the json string to _something_.  I chose to deserialize the json string to a dictionary of string => JArray because it seemed to fit the data well.  In this case the deserialization returned a dictionary of "data" => [ /* Array of records */ ].  (I chose JArray because it's Json.Net's closest representation to an array)